# issue getting proper promise failed function to run after broken promise

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, promise

I'm trying to reject a promise, and it seems to be working, but not quite as expected.

```
Parse.Promise.as(1).then(function() {
    var vendor = user.get('vendor');
    if (vendor)
        return vendor.fetch();
    else
        return Parse.Promise.error("No vendor found");

}, function() {
    //specific promise error for this particular promise
    res.redirect('/vendor/signup');
}).then(function(result) {
    var vendor = result;
    res.render('vendor/dashboard.ejs', {
        'user': user,
        'vendor': vendor
    });
}).fail(function(error) {
    //general catch all error controller
    res.render('error.ejs', {
        'error': error
    });
});
```

If the promise fails in the first section where it tries to load the vendor, I want the error for redirect.  Instead it's falling through to the ending fail.  What's the proper way to do this?  Isn't the second function passed to then supposed to be the one that it falls through to if it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic signature of `.then` is `.then(onFulfilled,onRejected)` - this means it takes the promise it is called on and calls the handlers based on the resolution of *that promise*:

```
 p.then(function onFulfilled(){
    // this gets called only when p fulfills.
 },function(){
    // this gets called only when p is rejected, if the above onFulfilled
    // rejects, this doesn't get called, instead it'll propagate
 });
```

Generally, attach a `.then(null,function(){` handler to hand;e exceptions in a code segment:

```
 p.then(function onFulfilled(){
    // this gets called only when p fulfills.
 }).then(null,function(){ // <- note the .then
    // this gets called only when the above promise _including_ the onFulfilled 
    // handler rejects. Since now the code is `.then`ing the result of the promise
    // created by the first .then handler.
 });
```

Also - use `.catch` in libraries that support it for clarity, unfortunately that's not parse.com promises.